# How can I use Rails.cache with a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, jruby

I'm trying to cache a hash inside my controller.

```
def departments_for_select
  Rails.cache.fetch("departments_for_select_#{session[:user_id]}", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
    Department.for_select(super_admin? ? nil : session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

But it does not work.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  caller
from org/jruby/RubyMarshal.java:145:in `load'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching

Comment: Why do you use `user_id` in one place and `session[:user_id]` in the other?

Comment: @Ruslan fixed just now

Comment: Have you tried: `Rails.cache.fetch(departments_for_select: session[:user_id])`?

Comment: Not sure what was going on but it's working now. Thanks!